# Remove gap in bootstrap layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I place 3rd div below 1st div ?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background:red; height:200px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background:green; height:400px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background:blue; height:400px;"">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See my original site then you will understand the problem.

This is my original website:- https://www.artguide.pro/paris-guide/  See the right site on screen 992px to 1199px. Better try to fix it on my website code.

Comment: Bootstrap has a grid size of 12. You have 18 in the row. not sure why you can't just add the 3rd div in a new row

Comment: This is my original website:- https://www.artguide.pro/paris-guide/ See the right site on screen 992px to 1199px. Then you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking to fix, but I did look at your site and made some column adjustments to get the responsiveness to work a bit better.

Here is a screenshot of the column classes I updated.

[image]